# When can we assume this identity about series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose we are given that
$$\sum_{i =a} ^b f (i)g (i) =\sum_{i =a} ^b f (i)h (i) \tag {1} $$
when can we conclude that
$$\forall i =a,…,b:g(i)=h(i) \tag {2} $$
?

For example, if $g, h $ are both linear and $\sum_i i f(i)\not = 0$ then $(1)\implies (2)$.

Is there a name for this theorem or set of functions for which $(1)\implies (2)$?

Let's suppose $f,g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: You might also want to assume that $\sum\limits_iif(i)\ne0$ for the implication to hold. A name? I doubt there is one.

Comment: You should be more specific on the involved functions; what is their domain and codomain? What means "linear" in this context? In general the conclusion is false:  if $f(1)=f(2)=1$, $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=-1$, $h(1)=h(2)=0$ then also $f(1)g(1)+f(2)g(2)=f(1)h(1)+f(2)h(2)=0$, but $g\ne h$.

Comment: @user59363: I meant [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) of linear, which your example $g$ doesn't meet.

Comment: Of course is my $g$ not a linear function and neither are my $f$ and $h$: their domain is the set $\{1,2\}$. In order to have linear functions their domain must be a vector space. Therefore I thought you should be more specific about domain and codomain of your functions. As the problem is stated now, one has to assume the domain of your functions $f,g,h$ is the finite set of integers $\{a,a+1,\dots, b\}$. However, it makes no sense to speak about linearity of such functions.

Comment: @user59363: sure, added "Let's suppose $f,g,h:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$."